# How to map array inside array Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

hope you have a great day!

i want to ask something, and i'm still learning about how to display array (mapping) when it got another array inside, here's what i mean:

```js
{
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
      date: moment()
        .add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), "days")
        .calendar(),
      title: "someTitle",
      people: [
        {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
          name: "someName",
          photo: "somePhotos",
          level: "someLevel",
        },
        {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
          name: "someName",
          photo: "somePhotos",
          level: "someLevel",
        },
        {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
          name: "someName",
          photo: "somePhotos",
          level: "someLevel",
        },
      ],
    },
```

and what i nead is i want to display them but i can't, here's my code looks like:

```js
{someList?.map((item, i) => (
              <div className="flex-none bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl w-[20rem] ml-4 px-6 py-6">
                <h1 className="text-[1.5rem] font-bold leading-none">
                  {item.title}
                </h1>
                <h1>{item.date}</h1>
                <div className="h-1.5 bg-gray-200 rounded-full my-2"></div>
                <h1 className="font-bold">someLevel</h1>
                {item.people?.map((people, i) => {
                  <div className="border-[#DCDCDC] border-2 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl flex">
                    <div className="w-12 bg-red-400 h-12 rounded-full mr-2"></div>
                    <div className="flex-auto bg-blue-600">
                      <b>{people.name}</b>
                    </div>
                  </div>;
                })}
              </div>
            ))}
```

the problem is, `item.title` and `item.date` can be display, but `.map` inside `someList` cannot

am i doin it wrong?

Comment: you forgot `return` statement .... `{item.people?.map((people, i) => {return (.....)}`

Comment: hey @KcH thanks for your comment, but can you explain it more? please..

Comment: broooo it works!

Comment: i hope you can answer this question and i'll approve it

Comment: That's fine  .... you can read about [Implicit vs Explicit return](https://waylonwalker.com/explicit-vs-implicit-returns-in-javascript/)